# OnClick of a button display a div (along with its CSS properties) in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building a web page in which I want a div to pop-out from a source page to another page.

Screenshot of the web page I am building:

[image]

`onClick` of Ticker Panel `Button` I would want the whole Ticker Panel div to pop-out in a new browser window with similar width, height, and CSS properties. Also, I do not want to display `Button` in the new window.

HTML file:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
        <h3 class="box-title">Ticker Panel <button class="btn btn-default pull-right ticker-pop-out" type="submit">Button</button></h3>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-header -->
    <div class="box-body">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Market Id</th>
                    <th>Ticker Price</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1.</td>
                    <td><span class="badge bg-red">55%</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2.</td>
                    <td><span class="badge bg-yellow">70%</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3.</td>
                    <td><span class="badge bg-light-blue">30%</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4.</td>
                    <td><span class="badge bg-green">90%</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5.</td>
                    <td><span class="badge bg-red">55%</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>6.</td>
                    <td><span class="badge bg-yellow">70%</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>7.</td>
                    <td><span class="badge bg-light-blue">30%</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>8.</td>
                    <td><span class="badge bg-green">90%</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>9.</td>
                    <td><span class="badge bg-green">90%</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>10.</td>
                    <td><span class="badge bg-red">55%</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>11.</td>
                    <td><span class="badge bg-yellow">70%</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>12.</td>
                    <td><span class="badge bg-light-blue">30%</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>13.</td>
                    <td><span class="badge bg-green">90%</span></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
</div>
```

I tried to do the following:

```
function nWin() {
    var w = window.open();
    var html = $(".ticker-pop-out").html();
    $(w.document.body).html(html);
}

$('.ticker-pop-out').on('click', function () {
    nWin();
});
```

But I only get "Button" as the output in a new window. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS selector is wrong.

```
function nWin() {
    var w = window.open();
    var html = $("div.box").html();
    $(w.document.body).html(html);
}
```

For the other problems mentioned on comments, here's what you need!

To recover all the css references from the actual page:

```
var cssReferences;
$('link[rel="stylesheet"]').each(function(i, item){
  if (item.outerHTML){
    cssReferences += item.outerHTML
  }
});
```

Using the same logic for recovering some possible css/javascripts dependency:

```
var scriptFilesReferencess;
$('script[src]').each(function(i, item){
  if (item.outerHTML){
    scriptFilesReferencess += item.outerHTML
  }
});
```

This is the script snippet to hide the button (It is formatted to get a better vision for you, and it have a Jquery Dependency):

```
var scriptSnippetHideButton = '
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(){
    var buttonToHide = $("#ButtonToHide");
    if (buttonToHide && buttonToHide.length > 0){
      buttonToHide.hide();
    }
 }
</script>
';
```

Finally, you have to include these new variables in your new page's header:

```
function nWin(){
    var w = window.open();
    var html = $('div.box').first().html();
    $(w.document.head).html(cssReferences + scriptFilesReferencess +  scriptSnippetHideButton);
    $(w.document.body).html(html);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out. It works, but I do not see the CSS properties of that div in a new window. Also, I do not want the `Button` to be displayed in a new window.

Comment: So, you must append a reference to your CSS file together with the html content and also, you'll have to or create a javascript to hide the button or delete from html variable. Did you get it?

Comment: I found an example online to know how to append CSS file in jquery. `$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">');` . Can you help me out as to where in my code should I add this?

Comment: Sure, inside nWin function: $(w.document.head).html ('css reference here')

Comment: I tried `$(w.document.head).html('dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">');` and `$(w.document.head).html('<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">');` neither of them work. Can you please let me know as to what am I doing wrong? Now the whole function looks like ```function nWin() {

            var html = $("div.ticker").html();
            var w = window.open();
            // $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">');
            $(w.document.head).html('dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">');
            $(w.document.body).html(html);

        }```

Comment: Did you check if the css file "AdminLTE.min.css" was correclty loaded in the new window? Check if the path is right, and inspect the resulting html to verify possible errors.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your are getting just the button class intead of the class you want to display. Try this:

```js
function nWin() {
    var w = window.open();
    var html = $(".classYouWantToAppear").html();
    $(w.document.body).html(html);
}
```

### Your code:

```js
function nWin() {
    var w = window.open();
    var html = $(".ticker-pop-out").html(); //This class reference to the button, not to the class you want to render
    $(w.document.body).html(html);
}
```

where the class "classYouWantToAppear" should be the class you want it to be rendered.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. It works, but I do not see the CSS properties of that div in a new window. Also, I do not want the `Button` to be displayed in a new window.

Comment: I think in that case you must redirect to the new page instead. It would be cleaner and easier for maintenance

Answer (score 0):

I always do such things by using query string. Add this code at the end of your page:

```
<script>
    (function ($) // to get query string 
    {
        $.QueryString = (function (a)
        {
            if (a == "") return {};
            var b = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
            {
                var p = a[i].split('=');
                if (p.length != 2) continue;
                b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
            }
            return b;
        })(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'))
    })(jQuery);
    if ($.QueryString["btn"] == "hide")
        $('#your_botton_Id').hide();
</script>
```

and for opening the window use this:

```
window.open(CURRENT_URL + '?btn=hide');
```

and if your current page has query string do this instead

```
window.open(CURRENT_URL + '&btn=hide');
```